# Add developer team in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, settings, project

I was still learning the ins and outs of Xcode when the new version came out and I just upgraded to Xcode 8, which gave me a bunch of errors in the projects I started in Xcode 7.3. I can't get rid of two particular errors:

"Signing for AppName requires a development team. Select a development team in project editor."

"Code signing is required for product type "Application" in iOS SDK 10.0""

I'm pretty sure I could've figured how to fix this in Xcode 7.3, but the project settings page has completely changed and looks kinda confusing right now. Where do I add development teams, and is it possible to add a default development team for all my Xcode projects? I also found the code signing section in the project settings, but filling all the settings doesn't make the error go away, so I'm even more confused about that. I never had to worry about this in previous versions of Xcode, since I never got to the point of actual app distribution. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you said you found, you can go to the General project settings and find Signing. There you may select you team. Additionally, you probably want "Automatically manage signing".

If the error does not immediately go away, try Product > Clean, and then Product > Build and run again.